# xdebug with Eclipse: restrict which paths are debugged

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

I am using xdebug under Eclipse to develop a PHP program. The problem is that *every* php page fetched from localhost triggers the debugger: My own program, even when I fetch it directly from the browser, but also `phpmyadmin`, the MAMP admin page, etc. It's a pain.

How do I get Xdebug to only start up when I launch a script with the "Debug" button in eclipse, or at least to only start for pages in a subtree below my document root (e.g., `localhost:8888/myapp/...`)?

In order to get breakpoints to work, I had to enable "remote debugging". 
I have remote debugging set to "ask", but that's still unacceptably clunky-- and an application like `phpmyadmin` fetches several php scripts to load a page.

My web server is MAMP on OS X, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

XDebug enable debugging based on it's own cookie, and you cannot set cookie path. You have couple ways to stop debug:

1. Stop it in eclipse, and rerun later (anyway in current version stop session doesn't work, fixed in nightly : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=460836)
2. Stop/start by chrome/fox plugin (its in general create/drop cookie) like https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/the-easiest-xdebug/
3. Use different hostnames/ips for same vhost. For example 127.0.0.1 for phpmyadmin, and localhost for your scripts.
4. Use different php instance (on wamp will be hard ;))